# Setup domains with åäö in IIS

Tags: iis

How can I setup a domain with ÅÄÖ in IIS?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Domain names cannot have accented characters, and are limited to letters and digits. A good example, if you are having any doubts is that you probably cannot name any Russian domain name with Russian letters. This is probably why you are unable to setup such a domain in IIS.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: This is not correct, as Oskar pointed out.  There are extensions and conventions to the browser and to DNS to support non-ASCII characters.

Comment: IDN provides support for a wide variety of local, non ASCII characters in domains, this may not be supported by all browsers, but it exists.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the special characters to punycode and add that domain to IIS (or any other webserver you might be using).

Example:

```
www.enemmän.fi
```

converted to punycode:

```
www.xn--enemmn-fua.fi
```

A punycode converted can be found here:

http://www.charset.org/punycode.php

Answer (score 1):

kolla det:

https://domanhanteraren.iis.se/start/idn/,%20txt:conversion%20tool

you'll need first to translate domain name with national characters into one in plain form. then configure your iis to handle such name.